# How to make gedit open files in a new window instead of a new tab?

Tags: 22.04, xubuntu, gedit

When I open a file in gedit and there is another gedit window opened, then the file is opened in a new tab in the already existing gedit instance instead of in a new gedit window. This can be very annoying, especially if the gedit window is on another desktop.

How can I set gedit to always open new files in new windows?

I am using Xubuntu 22.04 and the answers I've found about this issue are for older versions and do not work with my version.

Answer (score 1):

Customize the `.desktop` launcher for Gedit by settings:

- Set `DBusActivatable=` to `false` such that dbus is not used to communicate with the application
- Add the `--new-window`  option to the `Exec=` line so it looks like `Exec=gedit --new-window %U`.

The `.desktop`  launcher is found under `/usr/share/applications`. On my system, it is called `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop`. Copy that file to your `~/.local/share/applications` folder, and make the changes indicated above to that copy. That copy will override the system-installed file. Note also that there is no need to be root to perform this customization.